# Laravel Validator - Check custom validation rule after other rules get checked

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

How are you? Hope you are doing great

I need one help for `Laravel Validator`, i have created one custom validation rule like below

```
$validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'user_id' => 'required',
            'role' => ['required', new RoleExist($request->user_id)],
        ]);
```

See i have passed one argument to rule's constructor `new RoleExist($request->user_id)` but laravel giving me `500` error if i do not pass `user_id` in the request

The error is

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Rules\RoleExist::__construct() must be of the type integer, null given
```

I know user_id is not passed in the request so laravel giving above error, but here my custom rule should be execute after `'user_id' => 'required',`

Custom Rule Code

```
private $userId;
public function __construct(Int $userId)
{
    $this->userId= $userId;
}

public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
   return empty(\App\User::where('user_id', $this->userId)->where('status', '1')->first());
}
```

Is there any way to do the same

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you add the code of your custom rule class to your question.

Comment: Yes adding that

Comment: Added, can you please check once

Comment: If you are on PHP 7.1 or higher you could use `public function __construct(?Int $userId)` to allow a `null` value to be passed.

Comment: Yes I know that but that custom rule should be executed once the user_id required rule get passed

Comment: Why though? Default Laravel behaviour is to run the validation for all fields and I don't see a benefit for you to stop validating when `user_id` fails.

Comment: what you have there is equivalent to this `$array = [...]; $v = Validator::make(..., $array);`  the array is defined before `Validator::make` is called .... this is just how code flows ... basically you are not even getting to the call to `Validator::make` since you are erroring out on creating the Object in the array you are creating

Comment: Okay, i got your point but what will be the solution for that? as i need this custom rule

Comment: I maybe fixed it with making query result false

Comment: I passed 0 as a user_id if there is no user_id so the query will result in empty

Comment: how about you just not run the query if it is `0` then

Comment: yes right thank you for your help